# Can I split up my jQuery code into 2 .js files?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen similar questions but I think this one is slightly different.

I'm writing a website and since the nav and footer styling is the same on every page, I've put it in a separate file that I've linked to in every html file because this saves a few KBs of data.

The navbar is using some jQuery and I was wondering if there is a simple way to do the same for my JS files. The problem is that all of my code is inside a `$()` function and I don't think I can just make 2 of these, 1 in every file.
If the solution for this is too complicated I won't bother because the data this saves is negligible compared to the size of the images on the site.

Comment: *all of my code is inside a $() function and I don't think I can just make 2 of these,* Having two `$(() => { ...` is just fine

Comment: Show ur code plz

Comment: Every `$(function() { ... })` has a different *scope* - so if you have a function defined in doc.ready in 1.js, it won't be visible from doc.ready in 2.js - the solution is to *namespace* your *functions* and then call them as required from whichever .js doc.ready you like - as the doc.ready will run after the namespaces have been configured